# Can I add a UIImageView to an UIInputViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on a custom keyboard and want to add some UIImageViews to the interface. I can load a .Xib fine as shown below, but when I try to create a UIImage within the main view it causes it to crash. Do you know why this is?

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("KeyboardView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as UIView
    self.view.addSubview(myView)


    let image = UIImage(named: "grid.png")
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: 216, height: 216)
    var gridImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: imageSize))
    gridImageView.image = image

    //tried this- Crashes
    self.addSubview(gridImageView)

    //also tried this- Crashes
    self.view.insertSubview(view: gridImageView, aboveSubview: myView)

}
```

If I manually add a ImageView to the .XIB, it also crashes. I feel like UIInputViewController will not let you use a Image View, even though the documentation would indicate it's possible. I'm usually an idiot with these things so am probably misunderstanding the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIInputViewController/inputView

Comment: self.view.addSubview(gridImageView)  does not work?